# Can't get the two and three finger click on touchpad Thinkpad T440p

Tags: fedora, touchpad, wayland, thinkpad, libinput

I installed fedora 26 just before on my thinkpad T440p but I can't manage to get my touchpad working correctly, and don't really see what to do more...

```
xinput list
```

just returns

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜ 
↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                   id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13          id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf is

```
Section  "InputClass"
    Identifier  "touchpad overrides"
    Driver "libinput"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
    Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
EndSection
```

I have already read quite a lot of threads but none of them actually worked (i rebooted each time)

A strange thing that might help is that

```
libinput list-devices
```

returns

```
Device:           Synaptics TM2939-001
Kernel:           /dev/input/event17
Group:            9
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             97x69mm
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a
```

but I have the Tap to click and Natural Scrolling actually working, even if they are written disabled there...

So is there any other way to edit the libinput properties?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ok... It was quite dumb actually, I just changed "Click method" from "default" to "finger" in tweak-tools and it made it

Comment: ... and still valid under wayland in fedora 30